# Cron Job Doesn't Run

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I am new to using crontab, and I've been trying to get a simple cron job working. The code for the cron job is as follows:

```
 */1 * * * * echo "job every minute"
```

So just for proof-of-concept, I want to see this printed every minute. I have tried saving this cron job using both

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

and by saving a crontab file (cronscript) in a directory and enabling the script as follows:

```
 crontab ~/Documents/MyProjects/cronscript
```

which is the path for where the cron job is located.
Both of the identical jobs are saved properly, as I have verified by typing

```
  sudo crontab -e
```

and 
      crontab -e

into terminal and they both appear. I made sure there was a new line character saved after each command, and I checked to make sure cron is running by using

```
 pgrep cron
```

However, I am still not getting "job every minute" printed to terminal (every minute) which is what I believe these commands should be doing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Specify the complete path to `echo`, e.g. `/bin/echo` or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cronjob is running just fine, but the cron daemon (daemons in general as far as I know) have no access to stdout so cannot output messages to the terminal.

To test it you can, however, output what you want to a file using

```
*/1 * * * * echo "job every minute" >>$HOME/filename
```

which will output (and concatenate) the text to a file named "filename" in your home directory every minute.

Comment: I tried this fix, and it is not saving the output to my home directory.

Comment: Actually, I updated it in the crontab -e and it worked! Now I'm trying to run a python script (crontest.py) defined as follows:
 
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("test")

The script is saved in my home directory, and I have modified my cronjob to the following:

*/1 * * * * $HOME/crontest.py

However, it is not printing anything to the console. Any suggestions? Sorry I'm not sure how to get the code blocks in comments!

Comment: make sure your python file is executable. also it will still not print to any terminal. you have to do the redirection as before.

Comment: Cron's do NOT print to console, but they can output to files