# Crontab on Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron

I have been trying for a while now to setup a cron job on EC2 at no luck at all. Although the cron job is listed and runs, it just doesn't find the file.

Here is the cron job

```
*/5 * * * * python /home/ec2-user/monitoring/job.py  >> /var/log/script_output.log 2>&1
```

Comment: What is the content of /var/log/script_output.log after the cron job runs?

Comment: @Nigel : It isn't being created because permission is denied.

Comment: As a quick and dirty solution you can `sudo touch /var/log/script_output.log && sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/script_output.log`. That'll give everyone permission to do anything with script_output.log

Comment: The script isn't executing at the first place and this is the real issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what we've got here is [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337415/cron-job-not-running) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462633/cron-job-doesnt-run) [those](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cronjob-doesn%27t-run-daily-as-expected-920148/) [rare](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) cases when cron job doesn't run.

Here's how I would tackle this problem.

- I would run `python /home/ec2-user/monitoring/job.py  >> /var/log/script_output.log 2>&1` in bash. Just to check that the command can run in **normal circumstances**.
- I would add MAILTO=your@email. Just to get **emails** when something goes wrong.
- I would run `which python` command and use **full path** to `python` in the cron file. Let's say `which python` returned /usr/bin/python. Then I would edit cron file like this: 
  `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/monitoring/job.py  >> /var/log/script_output.log 2>&1`
- I would **append an empty line** to the cron file. Actually I would do this first. But I'm stuck on FreeBSD's default cron. You're probably running Ubuntu and using Vixie Cron. Couldn't hurt anyway.
- I would run `pgrep cron` in bash. Just to check that cron **daemon is well and running**.

In the end your cron should look like this:

```
MAILTO=my@email.com

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/monitoring/job.py >> /var/log/script_output.log 2>&1
```