# Cron not running on 12.0.4 but does on 12.0.5

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have one server that is triggering cron jobs correctly. This is the information on that server:

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

`crontab -l`

`* * * * * ( sleep 15 ; sudo /var/crons/NextQueueItemParallel.sh )
* * * * * ( sleep 45 ; sudo /var/crons/NextQueueItemParallel.sh )`

The server that is not triggering the crons:

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.5-x86_64-linode46 x86_64)

`crontab -l`

`* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; sudo /var/crons/ParseLogs.sh )`

I run the script manually, and it works. I verified the path is correct, and put this debugging code to see whether it was getting called:

`echo 1 >> /var/crons/test
php /var/www/crons/ParseLogFiles.php`

I run it manually, and get a 1 appended to the end of test, but does not appear by itself. I have installed the right cron and anacron services, and tried the solutions outlined here:

[php cron job not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927144/php-cron-job-not-running) |
http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/ubuntu-cron-isn-t-running-some-things-check.html | [Cron Job Doesn't Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462633/cron-job-doesnt-run)

EDIT 1:

I updated the crontab on the machine that currently is not working by issuing `sudo crontab -e` and the following line is now present (I verified by closing and re-opening):

`* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; /var/crons/ParseLogs.sh )` (followed by a new line or two)

That file is comprised of the following:

`echo 1 >> /var/crons/test
php /var/www/crons/ParseLogFiles.php`

I tail /var/crons/test (`tail -f /var/crons/test`) but do not see anything appended and the script does not run. When I run both of these manually (by copying the line), it does in fact run.

EDIT 2:

I did not have execute permissions, which is why it worked when I ran it manually but not on a cron. I issued the following command `chmod +x /var/crons/ParseLogs.sh` and it immediately began working. If you are viewing this and everything else seems to be working, check that! Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: This is not really a programming problem. [unix.se] might be a better place to ask. Check their help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `chmod +x /var/crons/ParseLogs.sh` for the crontab to be able to execute it. Running it manually apparently bypassed this restriction since my cloud provider created the default account as root.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that one of the servers has the `requiretty` config option for `sudo` enabled.

Assuming Ubuntu uses the same setup as Debian upstream, check `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory for something like:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

If you find it, remove it.

If you control the server, another option might be to move the cron tasks into either the root user's crontab or into the /etc/cron.d directory (the format for files in this directory specifies the user to run as)

Comment: `cat /etc/sudoers | grep requiretty` returns no lines. I do have control over the server, but I'm obviously not a dedicated sysadmin. It was my understanding that the cron was ran as the user who added it, so I thought this would be the root users crontab. How do I know specifically what cron tab this is running as?

Comment: If you use `crontab -e` it will edit the current user's crontab, yes. If you're doing that as root, you don't need to use sudo when calling the scripts.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond! I'm updating the post with additional details. Thank you for answering me this much so far!